# iterate json into bash variable

Tags: json, bash

If I have a json string in a bash script, how could I convert that into an array?

```
{ "name": "foo", "id": "123" } { "name": "bar", "id": "456" }
```

what I want is to be prompted w/ the name, and that tells me what ID (into a variable)  that I need to use.

something like

```
pick your poison:
1) foo
2) bar
#?
```

If I select 1, then id `123` would go into variable X, else if I select 2 then id `456` would go into variable X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the better approaches is to read the data in question into an associative array -- here, using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for parsing.

```
declare -A data=( )
while IFS= read -r id name; do
  data[$id]=$name
done < <(jq -r '@text "\(.id) \(.name)"' <<<"$json_string")
```

Given this, you can then handle your menu:

```
echo "Pick your poison:"
for id in "${!data[@]}"; do
  name=${data[$id]}
  printf '%d) %s\n' "$id" "$name"
done
read -p '#?' selection
echo "User selected ${data[$selection]}"
```

Comment: this is probably exactly what I need.  but I keep getting a syntax error.  "unexpected token <"   `done < <(jq -r '@text "\(.id) \(.name)"' <<<"$json_string")`

Comment: Make sure you're using `bash`, not `sh`

Comment: @veilig, you tagged your question bash, so I gave you an answer that works with bash. If you need an answer that works with `/bin/sh`, that's a (sligthly) different question; adjust the tags and I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: my bad - was my mistake.